# javascript fetch extract data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I setup this fetch structure (I learned it here:https://www.kirupa.com/html5/making_http_requests_js.htm), but I can't carry out of the function the data fetched :

```
var arr = [];
var dat=[1,2];
var prova = 5;
fetch('https://ipinfo.io')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(text) {
  arr.push(text);
  dat = arr;
  prova=prova+1;
  //console.log(arr);
  });
console.log(arr);
console.log(dat);
console.log(prova);
//document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = dat[0];

console.log(arr)  -> undefined
console.log(dat)  -> [1,2]
console.log(prova) -> 5
```

I defined the variables as global and modified in the function, but the global variables are not changed as expected, do you know why?

thanks in advance for support.

sorry I haven't found the answer to my question in the other linked question:
if I put the "console.log" inside my function it works also in my code, the problem is to make visible the results of the fetch outside the function as you see the modifications inside the function don't update the global variables.

For a normal function it works but for an async function not, why? and how to take out the data?

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns a promise. In the mean time the script will go to the next line outside of the promise, which is in your case console.log(arr);

Your code above is rewriten, using async/await. It makes code a lot more readable in my opinion.

```js
async function run() {
    var response = await fetch('https://ipinfo.io');
    var text = await response.text();

    arr.push(text);
    dat = arr;
    prova = prova + 1;

    console.log(arr);
    console.log(dat);
    console.log(prova);
}

run();
```